# Sticky menu for WP custom menubars

Tags: customization, navigation, menus, widgets

This seems simple, except that I am not able to figure it out.

In a wordpress theme, how can I make a custom menubar below the header image stick at the top after scrolling down the page?

Example sites are [www.riverviewford.com](http://www.riverviewford.com/) and [www.forexfactory.com](http://www.forexfactory.com/).

Here is the code I found on the net and am trying to use in wordpress. 
http://jsfiddle.net/uFq2k/3/

How do I actually call the script, and where from? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is the following:

1) Make a javascript-file and put the following content into it:

```
$(function(){
    var stickyHeaderTop = $('#stickyheader').offset().top;

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if( $(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeaderTop ) {
            $('#stickyheader').css({position: 'fixed', top: '0px'});
        } else {
            $('#stickyheader').css({position: 'static', top: '0px'});
        }
    });
});
```

2) Save this file in your theme folder as (for example) `stickyheader.js`.
3) Put the following code in your theme's `functions.php`:

```
do_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpse101288_enqueue_script' );

function wpse101288_enqueue_script() {
    wp_register_script( 'stickyheader', get_template_directory_uri() . '/stickyheader.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
}
```

4) Put the menu you want to get "sticky" between te following code:

```
<div id="stickyheader">/* YOUR MENU CODE HERE */</div>
```

or even better, add `id="stickyheader"` to the existing element in wich your menu is located.

Comment: Hi Mike,Thanks for responding.I tried, but its not working. I am using 'pinboard' theme. Here's the header content. http://pastebin.com/iaBf6SbA   I used the div wrapper for the menubar starting at line 28. Not working.

Comment: didn't work for twentyTen theme, nor for its child theme. Even tried what this link had to say: http://www.wpexplorer.com/javascript-wordpress/                 wp doesnt budge.

Comment: Did you received any errors during pageload (firebux console), has the element you wanted to get "sticky" the id `stickyheader` and you are sure the element isn't just hiding behind the content after the new style assignment? - It happend to be that I was in need of the same kind of script yesterday, so I used the same as you did. I didn't work for me either until I'd changed the CSS (`z-index`).

Comment: plz see my response added as an answer above. This site doesnt allow longer comments and code editing. By the way, its working for a child theme of twentyten but not pinboard. Here is the new header(menu code line 102-109): http://pastebin.com/SPKgBVrx

Comment: Looks good to me? I think you'll have to debug your html with Firebug to get an idea of what is going wrong. Can you send a URL of your website?

Comment: sorry...testing on local servers at the moment. Can you believe it, the stupid moderators have removed my comment in the answers section, which was actually a solution. I will follow your response for a while here, but I am not sure whether I will post anything here anymore.